# How to Copy TEXT format partitioned table to ORC format Table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

i have a Text Format hive table, like:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE op_log (
   time string, debug string,app_id string,app_version string, ...more fields)
   PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
   STORED AS TEXTFILE;`

now i create a orc format table with same fields, like

`CREATE TABLE op_log_orc (
time string, debug string,app_id string,app_version string, ...more fields)
PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress" = "SNAPPY");`

when i copy from `op_log` to `op_log_orc`, i have get this errors:

`hive> insert into op_log_orc PARTITION(dt='2016-08-09') select * from op_log where dt='2016-08-09';
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:12 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different ''2016-08-09'': Table insclause-0 has 62 columns, but query has 63 columns.
hive>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition key (`dt`) in the source table is returned in the result set as though it were a regular field, so you have the extra column.  Exclude the `dt` field from the field list (instead of `*`) if you're going to specify its value in the partition key.  Alternatively, just specify `dt` as the name of the partition, without providing a value.  See CTAS (create table as select...) in the example here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)